# Identity Server 4 add parameter to Login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a requirement to send an extra parameter from my MVC client to my Identity Server 4 UI when a user needs to authenticate. I've tried following [these](https://developers.de/2019/11/29/how-to-pass-custom-parameters-in/) [two](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/adding-parameters-to-openid-connect-authorization-url/) articles I found which explain the concept which seems quite simple, but either method I try and use the parameter seems to get added as a parameter to the `returnUrl` parameter rather then the named parameter on the `Login` endpoint.

#### MVC Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" };

    var connection = "YEPPERS";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection))
    {
        properties.Items.Add("connection", connection);
    }

    return new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", properties);
}
```

#### MVC Setup.cs

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // SNIP OIDC SETTINGS

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("connection"))
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("connection",
                    context.Properties.Items["connection"]);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

#### Identity Server 4 UI Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl, string connection)
{
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    return View(vm);
}
```

#### returnUrl parameter from above endpoint

[image]

As you can see the added parameter (connection) is in the `returnUrl` parameter, rather than populating the `connection` parameter as is what I thought would happen according to the previously mentioned articles.

Comment: So it doesn't work as expected, but is this a problem?

Comment: Well yes otherwise I'd have to parse the returnUrl to get the parameter out of it, which definitely doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't parsing the returnUrl seem right? First thing `BuildLoginViewModelAsync` does is parse the returnUrl in order to get some context.

```
private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
```

All you have to do is expand the `LoginViewModel` with a Connection property and get the value from the parameter:

```
var vm = new LoginViewModel
{
    EnableLocalLogin = local,
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
    Username = context?.LoginHint,
    Connection = context?.Parameters["connection"],
};
```